# strange shadows

Tags: modeling, transforms, error

They often appear after using rotation
what i need to do to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello could you please share the object itself, also explain what you mean by rotation (how was your object before rotation)?

Comment: As mentioned above please use appropriate title that matches your question.
On a first sight it seems that you have elongated or twisted polygons in that area, which doesn't work well with smooth shading. Showing the model wireframe could help.